# How to make that sound effect

Tags: vst

How to make that sound effect on this music video and singing after 1:50

I listen aoutotune pitch change but only voice sounds different and not like autotune, i mettin more music tracks with that effect. Thats sounds like voice mixed with synth not real human voice and i cant found vst oar anothe softare to do it that effect please help me fully. More exaple videos for
I listen pitch change again like on autotune but voice sounds diferent like robo voice or takbox

Sing on begin

Comment: Could it be a vocoder? Have you looked into those?

Comment: I think its two or more voices but not real human, sounds like robo voice or talk like

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a combination of two effects. The first is a delay effect with increased high and low-pass filtering on each repeat (like a tape delay plugin). There also seems to be increasing pitch glitches with each repeat. Maybe the autotune effect, the second effect heard here, is being run after the delay effect, and struggles to pitch-correct the repeats as they are lower fidelity?

The fundamental frequencies of the male human voice are roughly 85 to 180 Hz. If the delays are being high-pass filtered at, say, 250 Hz then the second echo won't contain any fundamental for the autotune to correct, so it is likely to have a harder time correctly re-tuning the incoming audio, giving the glitch effect on the recording.

Comment: "The fundamental frequencies of the male human voice are roughly 85 to 180 Hz." Do you mean "in the OP's recordings?" Anybody who seriously claims they are a tenor should be able to sing up to 440 Hz without using falsetto. A professional classical tenor should get to at least 520 Hz.

Comment: I'm referring to a normal male speaking voice, rather than any operatic performance. For OP's first recording this sounds about right.

Comment: No i need a software actually vst effect plugin or other programs for that